# GNU Assembly split string of integers to integers

Tags: string, sorting, assembly, integer, gnu

I'm working on a project for school.
The assignment is as follows:
Implement a sorting algorithm of your choosing in assembly (we are using the GNU Assembler). The input is a text-file with a series of numbers separated by newline.

I'm then trying to implement insertion sort.
I have already opened and read the file and i'm able to print the content to terminal.

My problem is now how to split each number from the file in order to compare and sort them.

I believe google is glowing at the moment due to my effort to find and answer (maybe I don't know what I need to type or where to look).

I have tried to get each character from the string, which i'm able to do BUT I don't know to put them together again as integers (we only have integers).

If anybody could help with some keywords to search for it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post your code, let's see what you have done so far (click "edit" under your question and paste your code). Also post a sample file (with "integers separated by newline").

Comment: Sounds like you need a very basic test in there... If it's an ASCII representation of a number, hang onto it and convert to an integer value with the proper place value.  If it's not and it's a newline, comma or whatever the separator is, start tracking the next number.

Comment: You can eventually avoid integers at all, and sort them as strings with modified lexicographical sort, when string "9" is less than "10" (accounting for the length of string first, then using lexicographical test for strings with same length) ... just make sure you don't have leading zeroes in input. :)) (this is more like "joke", than serious suggestion, just to show there are even different ways)